# ( in Java printf format string

Tags: java, printf

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double x=2345.6789;
        System.out.printf("My number is %(f",x);
    }
}
```

For whatever reason that single parenthesis is compiling and executing although no matter how many printf references I find, none list this as a modifier.  Anyone know why this works or similar cases to this?

Output of above code:

```
My number is 2345.678900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You weren't looking at Java references. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for *Java* format string syntax:

```
Flag ... Description
...
'('      The result will enclose negative numbers in parentheses
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a legal format but rarely used, we can found its Javadoc description:

> ```
>  // The '(' numeric flag may be used to format negative numbers with
>  // parentheses rather than a minus sign.  Group separators are
>  // automatically inserted.
>  formatter.format("Amount gained or lost since last statement: $ %(,.2f",
>                   balanceDelta);
>  // -> "Amount gained or lost since last statement: $ (6,217.58)"
> ```

Answer (score -3):

The round bracket between "%" and "f" in the printf statement is unnecessary.

To denote a floating number, the syntax is %f

Decimal number:%d

Single character:%c

Comment: The question is 'what does it do', not 'is it needed'.